# Get the scroll position of a WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, scroll

I need to add some decoration to the contents of a WPF TextBox control. That works fine basically, I can get the position of specified character indices and layout my other elements accordingly. But it all breaks when the TextBox is scrolled. My layout positions don't match with the displayed text anymore because it has moved elsewhere.

Now I'm pretty surprised that the TextBox class doesn't provide any information about its scrolling state, nor any events when the scrolling has changed. What can I do now?

I used Snoop to find out whether there is some scrolling sub-element that I could ask, but the ScrollContentPresenter also doesn't have any scrolling information available. I'd really like to put my decoration elements right into the scrolled area so that the scrolling can affect them, too, but there can only be a single content control and that's one of the TextBox internals already.

Comment: Maybe try to subscribe to ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged routed event? It provides information like extent height, scroll offset, viewport size (all in horizontal and vertical dimensions), maybe it will help. I'm not quite sure I understand you task completely though. But give it a try.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how to capture an event when the textbox has been scrolled (probably use narohi's answer for that), but there is a simple way to see what the current scroll position is:

```
// Gets or sets the vertical scroll position.
textBox.VerticalOffset
```

(From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.verticaloffset(v=vs.100).aspx)

I'm using it to see if the textbox is scrolled to the end, like this:

```
public static bool IsScrolledToEnd(this TextBox textBox)
{
    return textBox.VerticalOffset + textBox.ViewportHeight == textBox.ExtentHeight;
}
```

Comment: John, thanks, I've tried your IsScrolledToEnd. It usually works, but not always. The problem is you're comparing doubles with the == operator. I think there should be 1 line tolerance in this comparison, like this: `bool scrollToEnd = Memo.VerticalOffset > Memo.ExtentHeight - Memo.ViewportHeight - fontHeight;`

Comment: @Aleksandr Where are you getting "fontHeight"? I used "Memo.FontSize" and it seemed to work as intended.

Comment: double fontHeight = Memo.FontSize * Memo.FontFamily.LineSpacing;

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ScrollViewer with this method by passing in your textbox as the argument and the type ScrollView. Then you may subscribe to the ScrollChanged event.

```
public static T FindDescendant<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (obj == null) return default(T);
    int numberChildren = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj);
    if (numberChildren == 0) return default(T);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberChildren; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child is T)
        {
            return (T)(object)child;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberChildren; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        var potentialMatch = FindDescendant<T>(child);
        if (potentialMatch != default(T))
        {
            return potentialMatch;
        }
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer s = FindDescendant<ScrollViewer>(txtYourTextBox);
    s.ScrollChanged += new ScrollChangedEventHandler(s_ScrollChanged);
}

void s_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // check event args for information needed
}
```